# CSS Performance Profiler?

Tags: css, performance, internet-explorer, profiler

I'm currently working on a site, and somewhere in my mass of stylesheets, something is killing performance in IE.  Are there any good CSS profilers out there?  I'd like a tool that can pinpoint rules that are killing performance.

Before you ask, I've disabled JavaScript, opacity, and box-shadow/text-shadow rules.  The page is still jumpy.  :/  If I disable all CSS, it runs great.

I need a tool that can profile the page and report where the CSS bottlenecks are.

Comment: So it appears as if the rogue CSS rules are IE9 only.  That's right, IE7/8 blow the doors off IE9 on this page.  I double checked this result using a couple clean virtual machines.  The only environment that lagged was IE9.  :/

Comment: Another interesting point is that switching to IE7 or IE8 mode in IE9 eliminates the bottleneck.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

So, I finally got around to writing a JavaScript function that indexed all of my CSS classes on the page and then individually toggled them, while scrolling the page.  This immediately pin-pointed the errant class, and from there, I was able to determine errant property.  Turns out that `border-radius` on an element that contains many children (e.g. a body level `div`) performs ***incredibly*** poorly on IE9.

I've started a github repo for my CSS stress test: https://github.com/andyedinborough/stress-css

From there, you can install a bookmarklet to easily run the test on any page.

Comment: Nice work! That also explains why switchingto IE7/IE8 makes it work faster.

Answer (score 6):

The [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) plugin from Google has a section that analyses your CSS and tells you about inefficient selectors, perhaps start there?

hth

Note: I know its a Firefox plugin, but should help optimize a bit :)

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten about Page Speed.  Even though it's not really what I'm looking for, it is helpful.

Comment: One thing you can do which will identify the problematic area (s) is comment half the css, test it, comment the next half. When you find the half that slows it down, repeat but in that half. Then you'll find the rules that are taking the time. Just another idea whilst im having a google for you :)

Comment: The odd thing is I can't seem to narrow it down... almost like each rule is equally degrading performance.  :/

Answer (score 3):

Hmm, never heard of such a tool.

If you find none, things to look out for manually will include

- Any `filter` statements (the classic `alpha=opacity` and others - IE has a number of very advanced graphical filters that are extremely expensive)
- Huge elements (like thousands of pixels large)
- Huge background images - maybe remove them all for a moment?

I would strongly suspect the first point - alpha transparencies can be a terrible rendering bottleneck, especially on older systems.

Comment: Thanks Pekka, but disabling opacity was actually one of the first things I did.  Although it helped some, there's still a lag.

Comment: @Andy yeah, you mentioned opacity already - overread that, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I also have performance problems on a web project I'm currently working on. It runs well in Firefox, Chrome, even IE8. In IE9 it bogs down.

After some detective work I discovered that eliminating all box-shadow CSS lines improved performance considerably. I had shadows from banners, tables, boxes and tabs, each with just a subtle amount of shadow and blur, but apparently enough for IE9 to get all moody.

Comment: I had a drastic improvement on chrome mobile on nexus 4 when removing a single 115px inset box-shadow (in a transparent overlay div). removing smaller shadows gave proportionally smaller performance improvements.

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome dev tools used to contain a CSS Selector Profiler for doing just this sort of thing. You can see screen shots of it [in this blog post](http://perfectionkills.com/profiling-css-for-fun-and-profit-optimization-notes/).

The Chrome team [pulled the feature in Chrome 30](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265486) stating that:

> CSS selector matching is now reasonably fast for the absolute majority of common selectors that used to be slow at the time of the profiler implementation. This time is also included into the Timeline "Recalculate Style" event.
>
> As such, I believe the CSS selector profiler is not as useful as it [might have been] used to and can safely be dropped. This will also reduce the fraction of developers trying to micro-optimize already fast selectors.

You could try to use an old version of Chrome to dig into the issue, but I'd recommend taking a look at the [Timeline tab](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline) of the current version of Chrome dev tools with will show you how long Chrome has taken to calculate styles (where selector performance is affected), layout and paint the page.

Answer (score 0):

Opera is experimenting with css profiling in its profiler.

It can be enabled [following the steps on this page](http://my.opera.com/dragonfly/blog/style-profiler-preview).
Then open the profiler, start profiling, and refresh the page you wish to analyze.
Stop profiling after rendering finishes, then the results will be shown.