# CSS peformance profiling

Tags: css, performance

I'm looking for a way to measure/profile the time taken for my css files to parse and render on a single webpage.

Are there any dev tools/software available to do this?

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0):

There is another question on SO that relates to what you are asking.

[CSS Performance Profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173122/css-performance-profiler)

Here is the link to  Andy Edinborough's [stress test](https://github.com/andyedinborough/stress-css)

Also - you can check out [PageSpeed Tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) - Mentioned on the same page by Stuart Blackler.