Is there a way to find slow CSS rules?
For a while, I've noticed slow transitions on my web app. I spent a long time optimizing the JS, but I couldn't get rid of the lag. Recently, I changed filter: drop-shadow to box-shadow, then the lag went away.
Aside from trial-and-error, how else can I identify slow CSS rules? E.g. is there a browser with a "CSS performance" tool? If not, is there perhaps a list of slow rules that I can manually check against?
Edit:
E.g. a tool that says the "the filter rule is the slowest rule that took 50ms of CPU time"

Found this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173122/css-performance-profiler

The perf issue you're experiencing is going to be heavily machine-dependent - unless you're asserting that the exact same latency issue is experienced when you run Firefox and Chrome/Edge and that it also happens on other machines with different OSes/GPUs/drivers, etc.
